# Conditions for $\liminf(f+g)=\liminf f +\liminf g$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f,g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, then we have  $\liminf(f+g)\geq \liminf f +\liminf g$.
I want to find the necessity and sufficient conditions for when this inequality can  take "$=$"?

My guess:

1) Monotone

2) Non-negativity

3) Continuity, well this condition must be sufficient.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are function of what? ${\Bbb R}, {\Bbb N}$ ? Or more specific, the lim inf is under what limit?

Comment: Although not $L^p$, one can cook up examples which demonstrate how things can go complicated. For instance, consider $f(x) = \cos x$ and $g(x) = \cos(x+\alpha)$. Then liminf of each function as $x\to\infty$ is $-1$ but $$\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+g(x)) = -2\left|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|$$ can take any value between $-2$ and $0$ for appropriate choices of $\alpha$.